# How to set Prayer API in qml?

Tags: qt, qml

i've been fighting with this problem the whole , seen that i'm still beginner with Qt/qml
i'm trying to integrate an API in my qml existant project . i want that user could select the city and the prayer time showed up with  for the actual date ListView propery like this :
{ thesday 26th
fajr : 8:26
etc
}
The problem is this gives me many errors , as a beginner i don't have many methods to integrate my API in qml , is there anyone can help?

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15
import QtWebView 1.1

Item {


    property string selectedCity: ""
    property var prayerTimes: []

    WebView {
        id: webView
        url: "https://adhanmaroc.onrender.com/api/cities"
        onLoadingChanged: {
            if (loadRequest.status === WebView.LoadSucceededStatus) {
                var response = JSON.parse(webView.html)
                // Store the retrieved city list in a model
                cityListModel.clear()
                for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                    cityListModel.append({ "city": response[i] })
                }
            }
        }
    }

    ListView {
        id: cityListView
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height

        model: cityListModel

        delegate: Item {
            width: parent.width
            height: 40

            Text {
                text: modelData.city
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                anchors.left: parent.left
                leftPadding: 10
                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked: {
                        selectedCity = modelData.city
                        loadPrayerTimes()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function loadPrayerTimes() {
        if (selectedCity !== "") {
            var url = "https://adhanmaroc.onrender.com/api/prayer-times/" + selectedCity
            webView.url = url
        }
    }

    WebView {
        id: prayerTimesWebView
        anchors.fill: parent
        visible: prayerTimes.length > 0

        onLoadingChanged: {
            if (loadRequest.status === WebView.LoadSucceededStatus) {
                prayerTimes = JSON.parse(webView.html)
                // Display prayer times to the user
                // Access the prayer times data from the 'prayerTimes' property
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- I aim to fetch only the prayers name with their times
- API :[https://adhanmaroc.onrender.com/api/city/{cityname}](https://adhanmaroc.onrender.com/api/city/%7Bcityname%7D)
  The problem i have is nothing happen on my app , no result and no errors

Comment: Offtopic but I assume that using `WebView` to get and parse some REST `Json` data is an absolute overkill. You probably can use [XMLHttpRequest](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtqml-xmlhttprequest.html) instead. Using 2 `WebView` for 2 queries is beyond my understanding ...

Comment: I also think you are missing `cityListModel` (at least in the shown code), I think you want: `model: ListModel{ id: cityListModel }`

Comment: @folibis i agree for webView i searched more after i saw your comment . i tried to use XMLHttpRequest but the problem is they give an error as this module is not exist  i'm using Qt6

Comment: XmlHttpRequest certainly does exist in Qt6. [Here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6.4/qtqml-xmlhttprequest-example.html) is an example showing how to use it.

Comment: @JarMan Thank you so much , i had to make it simple from the beginning and use XMLHttpRequest